# Vim - Meaning of "vim: fdm=syntax..." line in plugins

Tags: vim

I've seen some scripts contain the following line

```
vim: fdm=syntax:et:ts=4:sw=4:sts=4
```

Initially, I thought it is override the existing settings of the user when the file was opened. However, when I use include it in my file, it doesn't work the way I expected it to.
So I'm wondering now what exactly does it do?

Comment: `:help modeline`, `:help foldmethod`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is what's called a modeline command (`:help modeline`). Settings are separated by a colon. So this is setting fdm=syntax, et, ts=4, sw=4, and sts=4. You can find out what each of these are by typing `:help fdm`, `:help et`, etc.